# .SetVisibility of an event

Tags: google-apps-script

Using appscript Google, I wanted to create an event for another user with their email address. (this is a booking platform and I would like an event 15min before booking to be created on his google calendar to remind him). 
As a solution, I coded the creation of an event automatically with this user as a guest. It works but the event also appears on my calendar (a public calendar, not my principal). 
I tried the .deleteEvent() function but it deletes for both calendars and the setVisibility function but there is an error with PRIVATE ... 
Here is my line : persoevent.setVisibility (calM200.Visibility.PRIVATE);
(persoevent being the event created just before and calM200 "my" calendar)

Thank you in advance for your help,

Comment: Why do you create an event for each guest instead of simply invite each user to a single event ?

Comment: Is there an other way to invite the user to the event than adding him as a guest when i create the event ? Because it adds this event in my public calendar also. (I also tried to send the user an email (ok) with a .ics file (echec))

Comment: I would suggest to use the advanced calendar API to do that, it is much more powerful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have looked at the advanced API but i just don't manage to hide/delete this event for me, now that i have invite the guest in my script. (just want the event to be in the user's calendar)

Comment: It seems you didn't get what I suggested. The idea is to create an unique event and to add as many guests you want. Every user will have the event in his calendar with exactly the same properties. Or did I misunderstand your request?

Comment: I will try to make it clearer: i have created an unique event and i add a guest (i need just one) and its working, the guest has the correct event in his agenda. My problem is that this event is also created for me in my agenda (not my principal but a public i have created and which i'm using in the script). I would like to hide or delete this event but just for "my" agenda. Is it possible ? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I see. The problem Is that each event had unique properties, this case will not be possible.what I would do is to to create a " garbage" calendar especially for this use and hide it from my agenda display ( what I can't see doesn't bother me )

Comment: Perfect, thank you for this idea!

Comment: Avec plaisir, my pleasure !